# Python Sckiit Learn Random forest: Order of predictors change results

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, random-forest, prediction

I am working on a classification problem using Python SciKit learn's RandomForest method.

I am seeing that the order in which I provide the predictors, change the result (not significantly but still enough to cause me a concern)

For example, I have a database `train` and `test` which each has several columns including the binary response variable (`y`). I want to use only certain columns as predictors and the way I am doing it is

```
preds=[x1,
       x2,
       x3,
       x4]
X=train[preds] 
Y=train[`y`]         
forest=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200,max_features=10,
min_samples_leaf=5,criterion='gini',random_state=2525)
forest_model=forest.fit(X,Y)

test_resp=forest.predict_proba(test[preds]) # probability 
Ypred=(test_resp[:,1]>0.45)
metrics.confusion_matrix(test[`y`],Ypred)
```

metrics I get from this code can change to some extent if the order in which I input my `xs` in variable `preds` (and in turn in `X`)

So a code like this which is identical to above code except the order of `xs` in the begining,

```
preds=[x3,
       x4,
       x1,
       x2]
X=train[preds] 
Y=train[`y`]         
forest=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200,max_features=10,
min_samples_leaf=5,criterion='gini',random_state=2525)
forest_model=forest.fit(X,Y)

test_resp=forest.predict_proba(test[preds]) # probability 
Ypred=(test_resp[:,1]>0.45)
metrics.confusion_matrix(test[`y`],Ypred)
```

can give different results. I can imagine this is because inherent "Randomness" in the algorithm but I was wondering if someone can tell me how to overcome such problem in SciKit learn or if I am doing something wrong.

P.S:  I apologize I am not able to provide a reproducible example. I have huge amount of data imported from several sources in this model and some of it cannot be shared publicly. I just thought this could be a known issue and there must be a way to fix it.

Comment: something doesn't look quite right there.  You assign forest with the classifier, fit to forest_model, then predict with forest.  Try fitting to forest alone and see what happens (i.e. just have forest.fit(X,Y) and not forest_model =...

Comment: @ivan7707 I am not sure. I think it does not matter. Whether I predict using forest or forest_model, it does not matter because I assigned the name forest_model to forest. I did try your suggestion anyway and it does not change anything.

Comment: hmm, taking a quick look at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py), it looks like there is some random bootstrap sampling going on.  That could explain what you are seeing.

Comment: btw, I think you will get more love on this kind of specific question on the implementation of a ML algo at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) which is a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I agree and I thought so too. I just did not know if it was a more statistical phenomenon or some problem in my implementation in python

Comment: Also I do see some improvement by increasing the number of trees, which makes sense. (Also makes sense that this may have been posted at wrong forum). I will wait for some more comments and then move it if needed